# How to launch a new terminal and execute a sh-script in the new terminal

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

I am using Windows OS with restricted options (no root user), and git bash.

I want to write a script that launches three local servers for testing, on *localhost:9092*, *localhost:9093* and *localhost:9094*

Since these serves are logging, I want that script to launch **3 new git bash terminals** and run the start script **inside of the new terminal**.

I know that *start sh* will open a new terminal, but how do I execute a *test.sh* script inside of the **new terminal**?

---

*For example the command should look like:*

```
start sh ./test.sh
```

*Then a new terminal opens and *test.sh* is executed there.*

Comment: I avoid Windows, but maybe try `START sh -c 'echo hi'` or `START sh -c "echo hi"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I do not have the chance to avoid windows here, but its not working.

Comment: Maybe your `sh` can tell you what it can do with `sh --help` or `sh /?`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I looked already there. Somehow I cannot believe that this is not possible.

Comment: `<PATH_TO_GIT>\git-bash.exe -c "<PATH_TO_TEST>/test.sh"` should work